# Web app telegram как создать

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, aiogram

Telegram относительно недавно выпустили обновление, где добавили возможность создавать полноценные web интерфейсы. Я пытался найти хоть какой-нибудь гайд как реализовать хоть небольшую частичку функционала, привнесенного гениями telegram. так и не смог найти, если кто-то знает как можно в этом быстро разобраться и тому подобное. Можете пожалуйста подсказать?

Comment: Ну насколько я понял без знаний JS ловить не чего.

Comment: Предастовленный бот телеграммом у меня не работает, ни на телефоне, ни на компе

Comment: Телеграмовский Web App это фактически обычный сайт, куда вы просто подключаете их скрипт. Как это сделать описано в офф. документации 

https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps

Comment: В действительности - это действительно просто сайт. Только - минус это или плюс, но вы можете на своем сайте создавать формы для совместной работы с ботом, через BotFather вы можете хоть сейчас навесить на бота любой сайт, который будет открываться по кнопке у поля для ввода сообщений.

Answer (score 1):

Оправляете  BotFather:   /setmenubutton  затем выбираете из числа тех, которые у Вас есть бота. Следующим сообщением отсылаете имя кнопки, затем еще одним Url сайта. Сайт должен поддерживать протокол HTTPS. Заходите в вашего бота и слева должна быть названная Вами кнопка. На десктопной версии придется несколько раз обновить сайт(у меня по крайней мере почему-то так),мобильная версия же сразу прогрузит вашу ссылку.